# KotlinMultiPlatform - Android Studio fails to build iOS application: failed with code 65

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I cloned the KMM starter project from here - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-getting-started.html and the Android app builds successfully. I am running into Error 65 when building the iOS application.

I'm on Mac M2 Ventura 13.5.2. Android Studio Flamingo. Xcode 15.

Here's the screenshot of the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWvsC.png). There is nothing helpful in the output!

I have run KDoctor and it passed -

```
~/AndroidStudioProjects $ kdoctor
Environment diagnose (to see all details, use -v option):
[✓] Operation System
[✓] Java
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] Xcode
[✓] Cocoapods

Conclusion:
  ✓ Your system is ready for Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile Development!
```

Any help on how to get the starter KMM project to run the iOS app? I have no local changes to this project. Other Stackoverflow solutions haven't helped!

I'm also unable to build the generated project via xcode. It complains something about shared module not available

Comment: 1. using terminal run `pod install` in iOS project folder. 2. when building in Xcode, open **Report Navigator** tab and check out build logs, there should be more than just code 65.